# Using Storyboards in iOS6, how do I modal segue to another view, but have that view have a navigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6

Perhaps navigation bar isn't the best term for it, but I'd like it to have the blue bar at the top with "Cancel" and "Done" buttons in the top left and top right respectively (as this is a to do list app).

Preferably not in code, how would I make this view I've segued to have those? Right now since it's pushed, it's just thrown on top of the old view right now with no way to exit it.

Comment: You could also use a tool bar since you have cancel and done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the storyboard select the presented viewController (the segue's destinationViewController)...

Editor -> Embed in -> navigation controller

Or... just drag a UINavigationBar from the Object Library onto the ViewController.

Then you can drag barButtonItems onto the Navbar, and set their Identifiers to 'cancel' and 'done'. Wire them up to the ViewController as IBActions to do the work.